# Undo API call after component destroy

Tags: reactjs, react-component, use-effect

I do API call on component mount using useEffect and depend of response do some state changes, but what if my component destroys while request is in pending status, how can I undo this request and all functions that try to change my state on success

Comment: are you talking about the aborting a request ?

Comment: What does mean `component destroys while request is in pending status`?

Comment: Your component should be independent. You update your state on success callback or adding some error catching.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes

Comment: @Satif I have callback on success and it works even when my component destroyed. Thats why I need some why to prevent it work

Comment: @Liana So reconfirming for a better understanding, assume two links are there home and products so assume the network connection is too low so on root component is home so in componentDidMount the api will call and get the data before resolving it the user clicked on products component so i need to cancel that api request. Is that its correct !!

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes absolutely correct

Comment: @Liana cool will update with working codesandbox give me some time

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS sure thanks a lot

Comment: What library are you using to fetch? Some can cancel, some don't have an API for it.

Comment: @zero298 I use axios

Comment: @Liana kindly check the answer and the codesandbox let me know if you have any clarifications implemented as per the comments , happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So using fetch you can do like this as shown below, you can user native abort in js

you can read more on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const Home = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const abortController = new AbortController();

    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
          {
            method: "get",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            signal: abortController.signal
          }
        );

        if (response.ok) {
          const body = await response.json();
          setData(body);
          setIsLoading(false);
          return;
        }
        const customError = {
          message: "Some Error Occured"
        };
        throw customError;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.name);
        setIsLoading(false);
        if (error.name === "AbortError") {
          setErrorMessage("Request has aborted");
          return;
        }
        setErrorMessage("Internal server error");
      }
    };

    getData();
    return () => {
      abortController.abort();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading && <span>Loading Data, Please wait...</span>}
      {errorMessage && <span>{errorMessage}</span>}
      {data.length > 0
        ? data.map(d => {
            return <p key={d.id}>{d.name}</p>;
          })
        : null}
    </>
  );
};

const Products = () => <>Products</>;

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/products">Products</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/products" component={Products} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59375006-so-yx01x)

Note: You need to open the dev tools and make the network tab throttling to slow 3g from online and open the console so when clicking on the products link the api will get cancelled.

I hope this will give a better view of this problem

happy coding :)